# Need help with error in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

this is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pprom.pk
FROM
(
    SELECT
      item_t0.SourcePK as pk
    FROM
      links item_t0
    WHERE (? =  item_t0.TargetPK   AND  item_t0.SourcePK  in (?,?))
    AND (item_t0.TypePkString=? )
    UNION
    SELECT
      item_t1.TargetPK as pk
    FROM
      cat2prodrel item_t1
    WHERE ( item_t1.SourcePK  in (? )  AND  item_t1.TargetPK  in (?,?))
    AND (item_t1.TypePkString=? )
) AS pprom
```

And this is the error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

**Edit:**

The question marks are replaced by PKs of the respective items:

```
values = [PropertyValue:8802745684882, PropertyValue:8796177006593, PropertyValue:8796201713665, 8796110520402, PropertyValue:8796125954190, PropertyValue:8796177006593, PropertyValue:8796201713665, 8796101705810]
```

**Edit 2:**

The query is executed deep inside some proprietary software system so I don't know exactly the code that runs it.

**Edit 3:**

I found one more query that's a little shorter but results in the same error message:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pprom.pk 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT  
        item_t0.SourcePK  as pk 
    FROM 
        links item_t0 
    WHERE (? =  item_t0.TargetPK  AND  item_t0.SourcePK  in (?)) 
        AND (item_t0.TypePkString=? )  
) AS pprom
```

Using the following values:

```
values = [PropertyValue:8799960601490, PropertyValue:8796177006593, 8796110520402]
```

**Edit 4**

I found the SQL code that is sent to the db after replacing the values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pprom.pk 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT  
        item_t0.SourcePK  as pk 
    FROM 
        links item_t0 
    WHERE (8801631769490 =  item_t0.TargetPK   AND  item_t0.SourcePK  in (8796177006593)) 
        AND (item_t0.TypePkString=8796110520402 )  
) AS pprom
```

I also tried executing the inner SELECT statement and that alone runs ok and returns a single PK as a result.

Comment: making your query readable would be a step in the right direction =D

Comment: What are those question marks? especially this part: `(?,?)`?

Comment: How do you execute this command?

Comment: if you run each bit individually?

Comment: Maybe no value for `TypePkString` is specified? Your values only show numbers...

Comment: Change `AS pprom` to `pprom` (remove the `AS`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find any obvious syntax error in your query so I'd presume the issue is the client library you are using to convert the `?` place holders into actual values. Your question edit displays a sort of dump where there are 8 integers but only 6 `PropertyValue` items. Make sure that's not the issue: `IN (?, ?)` requires 2 parameters.

## Edit

Try removing the `AS` keyword when you assign an alias to the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pprom.pk 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT  
        item_t0.SourcePK  as pk 
    FROM 
        links item_t0 
    WHERE (8801631769490 =  item_t0.TargetPK   AND  item_t0.SourcePK  in (8796177006593)) 
        AND (item_t0.TypePkString=8796110520402 )  
) AS pprom
  ^^
```

Comment: If there was a parameter missing would this result in the ORA-00933 error? I thought it might have something to do with the general syntax of the query (but as you might have guessed I'm not an Oracle expert).

Comment: Certainly, **if** it was missing. Your app might be filling it with a bogus value. (We know nothing about your code.)

Comment: Álvaro is right, the **`AS`** in `) AS pprom` is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my project today!